Blumberg's theorem
The Blumberg theorem states that for any real function
$: \mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$  there is a dense subset  $$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the restriction of $$ to $D$  is continuous.
In the original paper of Bumblerg [Henry Blumberg, ''New properties of all real functions, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (1922), no. 2, 113–128] seems to me that he considers function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and no on $\mathbb{R}$.
I ask a simple proof  or referement for Blumberg's theorem.
Ps. I have also found in ''Strange Functions in Real Analysis; Kharazishvili (chapter 5)'' a version of this theorem for function $f:(0,1)\longrightarrow (0,1)$ (because $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic) but 'the details of costruction are leave to reader'

This might be useful: https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2019.1586263

From p. 119: So far we have dealt only with real functions of two real variables. It is apparent that the considerations apply equally well to functions of a single variable and to functions of $n$ real variables. For generalizations, see Variations on Blumberg's theorem by Jack B. Brown (1983) and Metric spaces in which Blumberg's theorem holds by Bradford/Goffman (1960).
